# Three.js intersection raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js, dhtmlx

I have created some geometry and some functions to move and detect it.
 It works perfect but now I have inserted it into a javascript UI library http://dhtmlx.com/ and doesn't work well. The problem is this: for example using raycaster, it find intersection with geometry also when geometry isn't under the mouse. It looks like all geometries are moved up from original position  and draw is a fake.

I made an example in this url : http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs%20-%20Copia/contact_manager/prova2.html. You can see the complete code in the console.

As you can see in the live example you can drag the cube also if you click above it.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because mouse coordinates are document coordinates, and not the coordinates in your canvas.

In my applications I determine the correct coordinates for rays like this:

```
var mouseX = event.clientX - myCanvas.offsetLeft;
var mouseY = event.clientY - myCanvas.offsetTop;

var mouseXForRay = (mouseX / this.canvas.width) * 2 - 1;
var mouseYForRay = -(mouseY / this.canvas.height) * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: myCanvas is got by the id canvas id? @kovacsv

Comment: Yes, you can get the canvas by id.

Comment: And I recommend you to attach mouse event listeners to canvas, not to document.

Comment: I updated application following your code example but still doesn't work . . . I can't fidn a solution. You can see the app on the previous link I put. @kovacsv

Comment: Yeah, I see. Sorry, I have no more idea what is wrong, but it seems that the canvas is greater phisically than it seems on the screen.